# Alternate to match function in R that returns list of indexes

Tags: r, match

I am using `R 3.5`
I want to get all indexes that contain zero in my list

```
a = c(1,2,3,0,5,7,0)
```

result should be

```
[1] 4 7
```

should return the indexes as `match` will only return the first index in this case `4`

Comment: Yes I was looking for which function. Also it seems ctrl+k does not work in comment box

Comment: @nrussel that answer does not clarify that "which" function returns multiple indexes

Comment: No but it is certainly enough to point you in the right direction. Read the documentation for the details.

Comment: Oh Sure. Just read the context and topic heading. I would have read documentation if that seems relevant to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud read about function `which`:

```
> a = c(1,2,3,0,5,7,0)
> which(a == 0)
[1] 4 7
```

Comment: Yes which is the function I was looking for